# How to create using Flutter the _showMenu function, which dynamically builds the popup menu and allows to handle the selected option

Tags: flutter

The problem is this: I wrote using flutter, graphics editor, which allows to draw various shapes using gestures. I want to add an option: delete shape. To do this, need to tap on the shape and then a popup menu should appear with the option "delete". It is necessary to select "delete" and remove the object from scene. I need a simple function of type _showPopupMenu (). In it, need to build a menu and process the selection of the "delete" option. And it's all. Flutter has the function showMenu, but I do not understand how to use it in this case. I've found the link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12931 and tried to use the code, but I didn't succeed.